# Is it possible to set all characters to be the same width in the pycharm output window?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've recently started using the pycharm IDE for my python code however whenever I run one of my programs (It simply generates a random map for a text adventure game and assigns the different biomes certain characters) when the map is outputted the character sizes are all off and the map isn't an even square.

[This is what the map should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ll7G.png)

[This is what the map does look like (and it gets worse as more map is discovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcWkJ.png)

Is there anything in the settings of pycharm which can be used to set all the characters to the same width or do I need to just find different symbols to use which are all the same width? Thanks.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using a monospaced font for terminal output. It might be a little tough to do so with special characters, but a monospaced font is one where all characters are the same width. You can also play with your line height setting in PyCharm if you want all characters to be square.

The terminal font can be set in `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font`. Depending on your version, there might be an option for `Show only monospaced fonts` under Console Font.